# run java script with selenium python

Tags: python, regex, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website to scrape, here is the website source:

```html
<script>
    window.searchPageData = window.searchPageData || {};
    window.searchPageData['Product'] = { SOME JSON DATA }
    };
</script>
```

My objective is to extract the json data. How can I do it with selenium python?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please use ``` for code blocks as it gives you greater control over your code-block formatting.

Comment: @CypherX sure thanks

Comment: try getting the text between the <script></script> tags first. You could easily use `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` libraries to do that. You don't necessarily need Selenium. Now, just extract the string where it starts with   `window.searchPageData['Product'] = {` and endswith `}` inside the text within script tag. You could also use `regex` library for that.

Comment: @CypherX, Thank you I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**Overview**:

- `s`: Get the text between the `<script></script>` tags first. You could easily use `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` libraries to do that. You don't necessarily need Selenium.
- Extract the string where it starts with `window.searchPageData['Product'] = {` and endswith `}` inside the text (`s`) within pair of `<script>` tags. We will use `regex` (regular expression) library for that.

Assuming you already have the access to the content from the website and hence you can also extract the content from a certain tag `<script></script>` as text, here is a way for you to extract your JSON data, which what I understand, is embedded in the html-source.

```py
import re # regex library

# Define regex pattern and compile for speed
pat = r"window.searchPageData\['Product'\] = ({\s*.*\s*})\s*\n.*"
pat = re.compile(pat)

# Extract JSON Data
json_data = pat.findall(s)[0] # s = dummy data

## Output
# { SOME JSON DATA }
```

---

### How to use `requests` + `BeautifulSoup` libraries for this case

Since, I do not have access to your data (url or html from the url), here is a scaffolding of what you need to do to get what you want. But, obviously, I could not test it. I hope this helps.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsp

## Get respose object from the target URL
url = "http://your.target.url.here" # "http://www.google.com"
r = requests.get(url=url)

## Use BeautifulSoup to get a list of Scripts
soup = bsp(r.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all(name='script')

## ID your script from scripts
# Now you need to find out some pattern or 
# specify which script in scripts (list) has 
# your intended content
# TODO.... FOR YOU

## Special Case: Pattern located in a single place only
# If your regex pattern could be found only 
# in one place in the entire html page, you
# can do this alternatively.
scripts_text = '\n'.join(scripts)
# Extract JSON Data
json_data = pat.findall(scripts_text)[0]
```

---

### Dummy Data

```py
# Dummy Data
s = """
<script>
    window.searchPageData = window.searchPageData || {};
    window.searchPageData['Product'] = { SOME JSON DATA }
    };
</script>
"""
```

Comment: @sajedeNouri Please take a look at this. I have also included the boiler-plate code for using `requests` + `BeautifulSoup`. I hope this helps.